# Create a click through window for Linux

Tags: python, linux, xlib

I want to make a click through window. A window which I click but the click pass to the window below it.

I've found this two solutions for windows:

[How to make click-through windows PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968267/how-to-make-click-through-windows-pyqt) 
[I have a form that can "click through", i.e. direct clicks to the window below. How can I undo my changes after the event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711396/i-have-a-form-that-can-click-through-i-e-direct-clicks-to-the-window-below)

But I want it to work in linux. I study the xlib mechanisms but cannot understand how the window stack works. Actually I can get all the windows with `XQueryTree()` and found the ones under my window. But I don't know witch one are above.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11917174/2651371) if you using Gtk/Gdk.